# Second meaning of "sich zu etwas melden"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, reflexive

As I know the construction "sich zu etwas melden" has meaning of volunteering, expressing readiness to take some job.
Recently I found this [tweet](https://twitter.com/anarchopr/status/1666762919344840706):

> Hat die Tagesschau **sich** eigentlich auch **dazu gemeldet**, wo dieses junge Mädchen  öffentlich von der Horde primtiver Barbaren sexuell genötigt und erniedrigt wurde? Oder ist das etwas, was den "Guten" den Tag vermiesen würde, weshalb man lieber wegschaut?

The author doesn't seem to mean that Tagesschau has to "volunteer" for something. It looks more about reporting news to me. But this should be non-reflexive version of "melden", without "sich".

Can somebody please explain meaning of this usage of "melden" and what is "sich" doing there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a fine line between *sich für etwas melden* (to volunteer) and *sich zu etwas melden* (to raise your hand), and there's also *sich zu Wort melden* (to comment). The author of that snippet mixed the latter two phrases and left out that *zu Wort* part.

> Hat die Tagesschau sich eigentlich auch dazu **zu Wort** gemeldet, …

You have to imagine a classroom setting in which the grind always volunteers for giving answers and explanations.